# SP2007 Custom WebPart Carousel

Tags: web-part, 2007, jquery, content-query-web-part

I may get in trouble for asking this, but I need to know if it is even possible.

I am tasked with creating a very modern looking image carousel for our company's internal and external facing sites. I am pretty sure I could do this in just jQuery and the like, can't be too hard, except here is the rub:

I need to make this:

- A custom web part that can be used and placed on any page easily
- Able to reference a list where the images and text will be placed
- Have modern scrolling controls (left right) for the images

So, I am unsure if I can even do this in SP2007. I've not written a custom web part previously, but I do know C# fairly well. And I do believe I have the ability to create the carousel in jQuery/JS fairly easily.

I would ask for an approach on this if anyone has some insight.

Thank you!

Comment: what about that? http://www.ashokraja.me/post/SharePoint-2013-Carousel-WebPart-with-Nivo-Slider.aspx I already used it

Comment: @Gwny thanks for reply, but that references SP2013, not SP2007.  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Visual Studio and add a new web part to it. Next you need to enable couple of webpart properties

1. List Name
2. Picture URL Field

Once this is done.. Inside the webpart you should read the respective Image URL's and add those to a hidden html input element.

Now you can use jQuery to read the image URL from the hidden element and fire up the carousel plugin of your choice.

Comment: I was under the impression I would need to encapsulate all of the html and jQuery inside the C# code while creating the webpart in VS?

Comment: You can use the UserControl to code the HTML jQuery stuff.. also you can use Visual Studio 2010 to create a Visual Webpart and use it deploy in 2007 .. http://www.dotnetmafia.com/blogs/dotnettipoftheday/archive/2010/07/16/visual-web-parts-in-moss-2007.aspx  http://blogs.perficient.com/microsoft/2010/03/visual-web-parts-in-sharepoint-2007/

Comment: Awesome! Sounds easy enough! Thanks for the insight!

Comment: It will be easy if you have good experience in jQuery..